# Are there keyboard shortcuts in WebStorm for selecting/jumping to the next occurrence of a variable?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, find-occurrences

I know there are shortcuts for jumping to the next occurrence of the string. It's really annoying though if your cursor is on a variable named 'it', those shortcuts will take you to any string that is or contains 'it'. I'm looking specifically for the next occurrence of the variable.